# Two-cell custom lithium battery charger failing

Tags: lithium-ion, charger

I fabricated a 2-cell lithium battery charger on a PCB and I can't understand why it is not working.

I am using an [MP2672](https://www.monolithicpower.com/en/documentview/productdocument/index/version/2/document_type/Datasheet/lang/en/sku/MP2672/) IC and followed the design for a non-MCU-controlled IC (standalone). The datasheet is really thorough and I followed the schematic on page 39.

I have an LED draining to the "ACOK" pad; this is the valid input supply indicator. This is an open-drain output, pulled low when the input voltage is greater than VIN_UVLO and below VIN_OVLO.

This LED never lights up, but I read 5 V on the input. This is clearly a problem but I don't understand why this is happening. According to the datasheet VIN_OVLO is typically 6 V and VIN_UVLO is typically 3.45 V. These limits are not violated if the input voltage is 5 V.

I have checked for shorts around the IC, as it is very small. I didn't spot anything except a potential short from pads 1 and 2, but they are connected through an inductor so I think this is the real reason for the low resistance between the pads. I do question my choice of inductor though as I am not very experienced at this. I chose a 1.5 μH [SRP3212-1R5M](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/54/SRP3212-3002163.pdf).

NTC is a 103AT type and its resistance is 10 kΩ.

The IC's internal LDO supplying typically 3.6V is showing 0V.

The circuit is as below:
[image: circuit]

The layout:
[image: layout]

[image: ground plane]

What could be the issue?

Comment: The layout is a bit of a mess. Did you try to follows the recommended layout in the datasheet? VCC decoupling could be one of your problems if the IC is not showing any activity.

Comment: I see a lot of layout issues… especially the position of critical capacitors and the inductor. I see there is an evaluation board available, please check it and the layout. Especially the inductor part.  Page 37 gives also a hint. (Recommended layout).

Comment: Actually it looks like you have the output of an external LDO connected to VIN, which has a minimum spec of 4.0V. The MP2672 has its own internal LDO. It's hard to see, but your LDO appears to be 5V, so it's probably OK. https://www.omo-ic.com/chip/cfa/NCP59301DS50R4G.html

Comment: I do understand the layout is suboptimal, but I am not convinced that this is keeping the IC from functioning.  I would imagine it would just function sub optimally.  I have already lowered the charging current to 500mA when it is capable of 2A using Rset of 24k Ohms.

Comment: Just to make sure: most of the GND pads are not connected on your layout screenshot. Are they actually connected?

Comment: Yea there is a ground plane.  I can post a picture of this.

Comment: “Internal Power Supply
The VCC LDO is powered by the input power supply, and is used to power the internal circuit and MOSFET driver. When the input is absent, the VCC LDO is off. An external capacitor is required to be connected from VCC pin to AGND. The VCC output is regulated at 3.6V typically when VIN is 5V. When the VIN is lower than 3.6V, the LDO enters into dropout state and the LDO FET is fully turned on. The VCC output is not able to carry a current load greater than 20mA.” you mention vcc ldo = 0. It means Vin is 0 or lower than 3.6V.

Comment: The EN pin of the LDO is high?

Comment: I just replaced the IC and reflowed it onto the board.  I wasn’t sure if the old one was DOA or a bad solder job.. Sure enough with a new IC and solder everything lit up like it should! So charger appears functional.